get dimensions of video twitch extension
I am developing a twitch extension that requires me to position items relative to the contents of the stream. For this i need to know the dimensions of the video in twitch, which I was trying to get from the html element. It seems that the actual video has some baked in padding as the container contains the video with some black padding around it. Is there a way to get the dimensions of the actual video either from the html or another way?

If the aspect ratio of the video element, and of the actual video, are not the same - then you get black bars, either on the left/right, or top/bottom. The videoWidth and videoHeight properties should get you the real width & height of the video itself though.

Thank you for your response. I initially just tried this by pasting code into the browser console, which was successful. When I returned to try the same thing via the twitch extension apparently I am blocked from accessing the video element. Do you have any other suggestions?
